# A for cycle can't wait

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I force for cycle to wait for every XHR to be completed before it runs? I know a way which is in comment, but it kills real-time of percentage counter.

```
var data = new Array, per = 0;

WinJS.xhr({url : "http://index.hu/tech/rss"}).done(function(req){
    $($.parseXML(req.response)).find("item title:lt(5)").each(function() {
        data.push({
            h : this.textContent
        })
    }).next().each(function(ind) {
        WinJS.xhr({
            url : this.textContent
        }).done(function(req) {
            per += 100 / 30;
            $("#per").text(Math.ceil(per) + " %");
            data[ind].p = req.response.match(/<p>(.+?)<\/p>/)[1]
        })
    /*var req = new XMLHttpRequest;

    req.open("get", this.textContent, false);

    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(this.readyState == 4)
        {
            per += 100/30;

            $("#per").text(Math.ceil(per) + " %");

            data[ind].p = this.response.match(/<p>(.+?)<\/p>/)[1]
        }
    }

    req.send()*/
})

for(var ind in data)
{
    //console.log(data[ind].p)
}
})
```

Comment: XHR's are used in an asynchronous manner, so it would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a for loop for that, you could attach a callback function on the XHR request that checks if the stopping condition of the for loop is met, and then stops, or else makes the requisition one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wait using `setTimeout`. See line `setTimeOut(wheAllDone, 100);` below:

```
    var items = $($.parseXML(req.response)).find("item title:lt(5)").each(function()
    {
            data.push(
            {
                    h : this.textContent
            })
    }).next();
    var itemsCount = items.length;
    var doneSoFarCount = 0;
    items.each(function(ind)
    {
            WinJS.xhr(
            {
                    url : this.textContent
            }).done(function(req)
            {
                    per += 100 / 30;

                    $("#per").text(Math.ceil(per) + " %");

                    data[ind].p = req.response.match(/<p>(.+?)<\/p>/)[1]
                    doneSoFarCount ++;
            })
    });
    var wheAllDone = null;
    wheAllDone = function() {
         if(doneSoFarCount >= itemsCount)
         {
               for(var ind in data)
               {
                     //console.log(data[ind].p)
               }
         } else {
              setTimeOut(wheAllDone, 100);  // <<<<< Wait a bit for all to complete
         }
    };
```